# Nearest point on a line ( Spherical / Mercator projection )

Tags: google-maps, coordinate-system, geometry, php, spherical-geometry

I have a **line (Ax,Ay - Bx,By)** over a mercator projection (google maps) and **a random point (Cx,Cy)** nearest to that line, i would to know the closest point (transparent blue on the image) over that line to point (blue in the image)

**EDIT: to clarify that this is in a Mercator projection (spherical projection)**
[image]

Comment: this post has very useful solution that may interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120357/get-closest-point-to-a-line

Comment: That light blue doesn't look like the closest, the closest should create a 90 degrees angle when connected to the dark blue, is that what you mean ?

Comment: I made the pic by hand so yeah, it's posible

Comment: @vinayan The post you reference solves a different problem of finding the nearest point to a *line*, whereas what is needed here appears to want the nearest point to a *line segment*.

Comment: Colas: How long is the line segment and how far away can point *C* be? If those distances can be relatively large (thousands of kilometers) or if any of the points can be near either pole, a calculation in your projected coordinates (as offered in several answers so far) will incorrectly represent the solution on the earth's surface.

Comment: The segment should be around 20-100 meters long , the point from centimeters to 30 meters as much from the segment

Comment: @whuber - mmm...it still looks like that post is referring to segment after i read it once again :)

Comment: @vinayan You're right, that *question* is the same: but neither the accepted answer nor the several highest-voted answers are correct!  You have to read down to the low-voted answers in order to find one that actually works. Please consider downvoting the wrong ones and upvoting the incorrect ones.

Answer (score 2):

check out [this link](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/printthread.php?t=194400) , it made me use the following function to calculate distances to line segments.

In PHP:

```
function point_to_line_segment_distance($startX,$startY, $endX,$endY, $pointX,$pointY) {

   // list($distanceSegment, $x, $y) = point_to_line_segment_distance($startX,$startY, $endX,$endY, $pointX,$pointY);

    // Adapted from Philip Nicoletti's function, found here: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/printthread.php?t=194400

    $r_numerator = ($pointX - $startX) * ($endX - $startX) + ($pointY - $startY) * ($endY - $startY);
    $r_denominator = ($endX - $startX) * ($endX - $startX) + ($endY - $startY) * ($endY - $startY);
    $r = $r_numerator / $r_denominator;

    $px = $startX + $r * ($endX - $startX);
    $py = $startY + $r * ($endY - $startY);

    $s = (($startY-$pointY) * ($endX - $startX) - ($startX - $pointX) * ($endY - $startY) ) / $r_denominator;

    $distanceLine = abs($s) * sqrt($r_denominator);

    $closest_point_on_segment_X = $px;
    $closest_point_on_segment_Y = $py;

    if ( ($r >= 0) && ($r <= 1) ) {
       $distanceSegment = $distanceLine;
    }
    else {
       $dist1 = ($pointX - $startX) * ($pointX - $startX) + ($pointY - $startY) * ($pointY - $startY);
       $dist2 = ($pointX - $endX) * ($pointX - $endX) + ($pointY - $endY) * ($pointY - $endY);
       if ($dist1 < $dist2) {
          $closest_point_on_segment_X = $startX;
          $closest_point_on_segment_Y = $startY;
          $distanceSegment = sqrt($dist1);
       }
       else {
          $closest_point_on_segment_X = $endX;
          $closest_point_on_segment_Y = $endY;
          $distanceSegment = sqrt($dist2);
       }
    }

    return array($distanceSegment, $closest_point_on_segment_X, $closest_point_on_segment_Y);
}
```

You can then use projection functions to calculate distances,  I'm using the above formula to calculate the time at that point given a average speed and it works really well.

If you want a good PHP library to calculate distances between coordinates in PHP, check out [GeoCalc class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geocalc-php/files/)

Comment: Hey Glenn Plas, your class seem to have a **little offset** to the left or right,i made a screenshot on Google earth you will see that offset, the pic:[link](http://i48.tinypic.com/v4nwci.jpg), the code i used `point_to_line_segment_distance(41.421649, 2.600410, 41.413851,  2.594356, 41.415710, 2.600638))`

Comment: It's not my class, just found it after searching a lot ;-)  But I use 8 digits precision in my problems, you seem to use 6.  That could be the reason, I never noticed any offset here.  Thanks for pointing it out, I will doublecheck this soon as I need to know.

Comment: Maybe you are rihgt, i can't obtain more decilmas on gEarth, btw in my last pic the segment was 1000 meters long, the offset was ~110meters

Comment: That's about the scale I use it on, no more than that.  I use it to see at what time a bus (public transport) passes a stop the closest.  I am going to doublecheck it though and put it in a map to 'see' if it projects well on a sphere.

Comment: Oh... I thought that function was made for spherical projections, so now i understand the offset

Comment: That could indeed be the offset, like I said, I only use it on very small scale so the error margin must be really low using 8 digits.  It's indeed just math, not geo-math :)

Comment: I just checked your results on a mercator projection in Google earth, it's about 16 meters off.  But it sure looks like it's more...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6878/discussion-between-colas-and-glenn-plas)

Answer (score 1):

you can use computeDistanceBetween() function from [google map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=pl-PL).

```
distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(firstCoord, secondCoord);
```

> The distance between two points is the length of the shortest path
>   between them. This shortest path is called a geodesic. On a sphere all
>   geodesics are segments of a great circle. To compute this distance,
>   call computeDistanceBetween(), passing it two LatLng objects.
>
> You may instead use computeLength() to calculate the length of a given
>   path if you have several locations

i hope it helps you...

Comment: first  I need to know the point (light blue) to compute the distance between

Comment: My solution below does that, the point on the segment is unknown.  I actually have a rather similar problem/solution as mentioned.  You can safely use these on small scale's.